# I lose draggable functionality when I binding items in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, binding, fullcalendar

I have fullCalendar like this:

[image]

And I would like to load stores (DALIA GLAMOUR; DALIA 15...) when I change select. But if I write stores in HTML like this:

```
<div id='row'>
                    <div id='external-events'>
                        <div id='external-events-listing'>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2 fc-event" style="background-color:#1abc9c;">
                                PTO. CARMEN
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2 fc-event" style="background-color:#d35400;">
                                DALIA GLAMOUR
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2 fc-event" style="background-color:#9b59b6;">
                                DALIA 15
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2 fc-event" style="background-color:#34495e;">
                                DALIA 5
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2 fc-event" style="background-color:#3498db;">
                                SABINA CASINO
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2 fc-event" style="background-color:#95a5a6;">
                                SASHA LIMONES
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2 fc-event" style="background-color:#f39c12;">
                                SAM P.BLANCA
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2 fc-event" style="background-color:#f1c40f;">
                                SAM DEILAND
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2 fc-event" style="background-color:#e74c3c;">
                                BAJA
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2 fc-event" style="background-color:#27ae60;">
                                VACACIONES
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <p>
                        <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' checked='checked' />
                        <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id='calendar'></div>
                    <div style='clear:both'></div>
                </div>
```

It works. But now, I have an ajax y load store like this:

```
<div id='row'>
                    <div id='external-events'>

                        <div id='external-events-listing' >
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2 fc-event" ng-repeat="store in vm.stores | orderBy:'store.id' " id="{{store.id}}" style="background-color:{{store.color}}; text-transform: uppercase;">
                                {{store.name}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <p>
                        <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' checked='checked' />
                        <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id='calendar'></div>
                    <div style='clear:both'></div>
                </div>
```

I have this ajax in my javascript:

```
  ajax.sendApiRequest({zone: vm.store.touristArea}, "GET", "store").then(
        function(response) {
          vm.stores = response.data.concat(constants.STORE_EVENTS);
          console.log("vm.stores", vm.stores)
        },
        (function(error) {

        })
    );
```

But it doesn't work. I saw in inspector, that in first case (without ajax), div with fc-event class, has "ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" class, but in the second case, not. Any idea?

Comment: do you run some code to make the elements draggable? If so, you probably need to run it again after you load the new elements via ajax and apply it to the new elements.

Comment: No, I do that I write in the question

Comment: The only code in the question is the ajax request. The docs at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/droppable/ say " You must download the appropriate jQuery UI files and _initialize a draggable element_". Initialising a draggable element involves doing something like `$( "#draggable" ).draggable();` as per the demo at http://jqueryui.com/draggable/. I assume you have something like that elsewhere in your code, but not shown in this question?

Comment: I resolved the problem. I put 
    $timeout(function() {
      initializeFullCalendar();
    }, 3000);

Comment: This will only work as long as your ajax request doesn't take longer than the timeout period. If you have some network issue it could easily take longer and then it will fail again. You'd be better to put the call to initializeFullCalendar in the "then" callback of the ajax request, then you can guarantee it will not run beforehand.